# Problem in Javascript colors and canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have used this code to exactly try to have the RGB code of color:

```
var huePixel = HueCanvas.css('background-color').match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);//["rgb(0, 70, 255", "0", "70", "255"]
var svPixel = SVCanvas.get(0).getContext("2d").getImageData(satPos,valPos,1,1).data;
//opacity*original + (1-opacity)*background = resulting pixel
var opacity =(svPixel[3]/255);
var r =parseInt((opacity*svPixel[0])+((1-opacity)*huePixel[1]));
var g =parseInt((opacity*svPixel[1])+((1-opacity)*huePixel[2]));
var b =parseInt((opacity*svPixel[2])+((1-opacity)*huePixel[3]));
```

The problem is that in some pixels , the RGB is not exactly the same . If i use Math.round than parseInt there is more problems , and more pixels have little changes than real ones.

I know that the problem is in `var opacity =(svPixel[3]/255);` , but i dont know how to put the equation to not have that problems.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: What's the value of svPixel before you set opacity?

Comment: svPixel[3] runs from 0 to 255.

Comment: Are you just changing one pixel or do you intend to blend the entire canvas contents with the background?  If you set canvas pixels to have opacity < 255 they will blend with the underlying elements and background already, without additional effort.

Comment: Yes , but what i need is to take the colour of one pixel not all the canvas . I was trying to not blend it , cause all times i change that colour ill must change it . But i think ill must do it. The only problem that i see in that is the memory that can take javascript and canvas changuing colour many times.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the definite answer to your question (I'm not even sure I understand the question itself), but I'll take a shot.

It appears that you're trying to calculate the RGB value that you see when something else (the browser?) blends a non-opaque canvas on top of opaque background. (Are you sure this is the right thing to do at all?)

First, please don't use `parseInt` to round a number. It's used [to parse strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and you should use it to convert huePixel[i] to an integer: `parseInt(huePixel[i], 10)` (note that I specify the radix explicitly to avoid numbers being parsed as octal).

To round values, you should use [`Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) methods: `Math.round` (to closest integer), `Math.ceil` (round up) or `Math.floor` (round down).

Maybe the problem you're having is caused by rounding errors (hard to say without the specific inputs and expected outputs of the calculation). To minimize the rounding errors, you could try rewriting the formula like this:

```
(opacity * svPixel[0]) + ((1-opacity) * huePixel[1]) =
  huePixel[1] + opacity * (svPixel[0]-huePixel[1]) =
  huePixel[1] + svPixel[3] * (svPixel[0]-huePixel[1]) / 255
```